# Can I use google Drive to host asp.net site?

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I want to host a site for my **university project** can I host it on Google drive? or you can tell me how to manage data base using java script

Comment: You can host a website without server side scripting. [This](http://nistencorp.com/) is an example of static pages being hosted on drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Windows Azure with SQL Server CE database. It offers 10 websites for free. See more at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/net/aspnet/

Answer (score 3):

Quote https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

> With Drive, you can make web resources — like HTML, CSS, and
>   Javascript files — viewable as a website. ...  Google Drive does not
>   support web resources that make use of server-side scripting languages
>   like PHP.

Since ASP.NET is a server-side technology, it will not work with Google Drive.

Hosting a regular database will not be possible too but it depends what do you mean by "database". For example, you can try to use Google Spreadsheet as explained here at http://dataist.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/using-google-spreadsheet-as-a-database/

If you a looking for a free of charge service, then google for "free asp.net hosting", e.g. this one is free (ads banners to your site) https://somee.com/FreeAspNetHosting.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot host asp.net site on google drive.

Answer (score 1):

No Google drive doesn't support hosting of web site containing server side script language like Asp.net, php.

for managing database in javascript, you can use TaffyDB. [here](http://www.taffydb.com/workingwithdata) is the link of it.

Answer (score 1):

My advice for a university project would be to contact somebody at the university and ask for hosting. Given that it's for work you've been given there, I'd be quite surprised if they weren't willing to help.